# JAXB get element if atribute equals xxx

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

So I have little problem. My XML code looks like this:

```
<Images>
    <boxart side="back" width="1525" height="2162" thumb="boxart/thumb/original/back/2-1.jpg">boxart/original/back/2-1.jpg</boxart>
    <boxart side="front" width="1525" height="2160" thumb="boxart/thumb/original/front/2-1.jpg">boxart/original/front/2-1.jpg</boxart>
    <banner width="760" height="140">graphical/2-g2.jpg</banner><banner width="760" height="140">graphical/2-g3.jpg</banner>
</Images>
```

And I want to get only `XmlElement` where atribute is "front". How can I do it? I tried something like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Images")
public class Image {
    private String boxart;

    public String getBoxart() {
        return boxart;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "boxart")
    public void setBoxart(String boxart) {
        this.boxart = boxart;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

Image class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Images")
public class Image {
    private List<Boxart> boxarts;

    public List<Boxart> getBoxarts() {
        return boxarts;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "boxart")
    public void setBoxarts(List<Boxart> boxarts) {
        this.boxarts = boxarts;
    }
}
```

Boxart class:

```
public class Boxart {

    @XmlAttribute(name="side")
    private String side;
    @XmlAttribute(name="thumb")
    private String thumb;

    public String getSide() {
        return side;
    }

    public void setSide(String side) {
        this.side = side;
    }

    public String getThumb() {
        return thumb;
    }

    public void setThumb(String thumb) {
        this.thumb = thumb;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see front attribute in provided XML.Better way is write XSD and Generate Java Classes using that. I have made evey field as optional as I am not sure which all attributes are mandatory.

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Images">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="boxart" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="side" use="optional"/>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="width" use="optional"/>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="height" use="optional"/>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="thumb" use="optional"/>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="front" use="optional"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="banner" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="width" use="optional"/>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="height" use="optional"/>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="front" use="optional"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Save this file as some.xsd and place in resources folder in eclipse. Right click on xsd file and Generate ->JAXB Classes.

It will generate two classes one Images.java and ObjectFactory.java

**NOTE:** If you are using JRE in stead of JDK you will get below error.

```
   Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.XJCFacade
```

From here on its simple you can use JAXB to get values of whatever attribute you want.